# How to point from domain to the target

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I would like to use cloudflare to use DNS management instead of Route53.

I added source code and set up EC2 and Loadbalancer, but I don't know which ipaddress or DNS name(A record) should be a target.

I set up with DNS name from loadbalancer, and it works now.

However, when I go to the public IP address from Instance, it works as well.

Which one do I need to set up with between Public DNS (IPv4) from Instances tab or DNS name (A record) from loadbalancers tabs

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a load balancer in front of your instance(s) then use the CNAME of the load balancer.

You should update your instances security group to only allow http/https from the load balancer. Additionally if you're able to recreate the instance put it into a private subnet.

Comment: Thank you for replying to me, I updated instances security group.